# Commutation relation of spin 1-system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, operators

Given the operator $T_i$ such that,

$$T_i = -\frac{i}{2} \sum_{j,k} \epsilon_{ijk} \hbar (|{j}\rangle\langle{k}| - |{k}\rangle\langle{j}|)$$

Prove $[T_i,T_j] = \sum_{k} i\hbar \epsilon_{ijk}T_k$.

What I have done is take the product $T_i T_j$ such that,

\begin{align}
T_iT_j & = -\frac{1}{4} \sum_{ablm} \epsilon_{iab} \epsilon_{jlm} (|{a}\rangle\langle{b}| - |{b}\rangle\langle{a}|) (|{l}\rangle\langle{m}| - |{m}\rangle\langle{l}|)
\\
T_iT_j & = -\frac{1}{4} \sum_{ablm} \epsilon_{iab} \epsilon_{jlm} (\delta_{bl} |{a}\rangle\langle{m}| - \delta_{bm} |{a}\rangle\langle{l}| - \delta_{al}|{b}\rangle\langle{m}| + \delta_{am}|{b}\rangle\langle{l}|)
\end{align}

However, I am not sure how to prove it using this general case using brakets. Although I know this can be proved by going to the representation of each matrices, I want to prove it usng brakets and levi civita symbols.

Comment: Do you understand that $\langle a| m\rangle=\delta_{am}$ and your [contracted identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Product) ?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have edited my answer but it still does not ring a bell since the deltas take different indices, for example $bl$ and $bm$.

Comment: Do you know how to contract tensors/matrices?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am a bit familiar on how to take the sum of doubly occurring indices and contracting but I am not sure how to do it in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints:

1. Whenever you have a summation that goes over a Kronecker delta, you can just cancel out one of the indices, so that e.g.
   $$
   \sum_{ij}a_i b_j \delta_{ij}  = \sum_{i}a_i b_i.
   $$
   For your specific case, you can do this term-wise, so that e.g.
   \begin{align}
    \sum_{ablm} \epsilon_{iab} \epsilon_{jlm} \delta_{bl} |{a}\rangle\langle{m}| 
   =
    \sum_{alm} \epsilon_{ial} \epsilon_{jlm}  |{a}\rangle\langle{m}|.
   \end{align}
2. Following on from that, if you have Levi-Civita symbols contracted over one of their shared indices (with nothing else riding on that index), they decompose into a pair of Kronecker deltas,
   $$
   \sum_i \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} = \delta_{jl}\delta_{km} - \delta_{jm}\delta_{kl},
   $$
   since only those combinations ($j=l$ and $k=m$, or $j=m$ and $k=l$) will give a nonzero result on the left-hand side.

The rest is for you to power through.